# Vector spaces dimensions unclear theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

While studying vector spaces I came across this theorem (see image) which does not make any sense to me. Is it possible that in the last row they meant $\;\{v_i\}^k_{i=1} \;$
or something similar? Even that does not make too much sense to me... Could someone explain me why the theorem is true?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Unclear theorem]

Comment: The theorem statement is sensible.  It is describing the *extension* of a linearly independent set of $k$ vectors (where $k\le n$, the dimension of $V$) to a basis for $V$.  To begin, think about just one linearly independent (i.e. nonzero) vector being incorporated into a complete basis.

Comment: As an aside, the language of the question is extremely sloppy. What if $v_2=v_1$ and $k=2$ for instance? Then one sees it makes no sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement just means that, on a $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, if you have a set $A$ with $k$ linearly independent vectors (with $k<n$), there is always a set $B$ with $n-k$ vectors such that $A\cup B$ is a basis $V$.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask a (probably stupid) follow up question? Wouldn't what you - and the theorem - say, mean that the set B could be linearly dependent? Thus A ∪ B would cause the basis to be linearly dependent, which defies the definition of a basis.

Comment: @ToTom There is *no way* that $B$ can be linearly dependent. A subset of a basis is  *never* linearly dependent.

Comment: True, thank you! I didn't read the fact that the starting set is a basis.

Answer (score 1):

Any set of $k$ linearly independent vectors, with $k\lt n$,  can be extended to a basis for $V$.

Answer (score 1):

Give a set of vectors $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\},$
then another way to write that is $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^k.$

But we are also given that the vector space $V$ has a basis of $n$ vectors.
Therefore *every* basis of $V$ must have $n$ vectors.

We are given $k \leq n.$ So it is possible that $k = n,$ which would be fine;
in that case $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^k$ contains $n$ linearly independent vectors
and it is a basis of $V.$

But since we are *only* told that $k \leq n,$ not told that $k = n,$ it is also possible that $k < n,$ is it not?
And in *that* case, $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^k$ does not contain enough vectors to be a basis of $V.$ So $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^k$ is definitely not the basis we're looking for in the general case.

What the theorem says is that at least one of the possible sets of basis vectors of $V$ has the same first $k$ vectors as our set $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^k.$
The other vectors of that basis obviously are not in $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^k$
and are linearly independent of $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^k.$

We number the "new" vectors $v_{k+1}, v_{k+2}, \ldots v_n$ --there are $n - k$ vectors in that list-- and now we can write $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n,$
where the first $k$ vectors are the ones we already had and the rest are "new."